# Having trouble using unnamed objects inside of for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, pygame, nested

The code is from a program that animates balls moving across the screen using Python and Pygame. All classes and functions just deal with data manipulation,  the main class here being `Particle`.  All of the actual construction and function calling occurs in these few lines:

```
number_of_particles = 10
my_particles = []
for n in range(number_of_particles):
    size = random.randint(20, 20)
    x = random.randint(size, width-size)
    y = random.randint(size, height-size)
    color = (100,0,100)
    particle = Particle(x, y, color, size)
    particle.speed = 1
    particle.angle = random.uniform(0, math.pi*2)
    my_particles.append(particle)

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(background_color)
    for i, particle in enumerate(my_particles):
        particle.move()
        particle.getnumber()
        particle.bounce()
        for particle2 in my_particles[i+3:]:            
            collide(particle, particle2)
        particle.display()
pygame.display.flip()`
```

I understand that the list holds the location of the objects in memory, and that the for loop used to create them doesn't name them, but does give them separate parameters. The functional loop after the creation loop iterates through all of the objects and updates their states, with the collision function occurring inside of the loop that cycles through all of the other particles not being iterated in the functional loop. What I don't understand is how it is selecting these objects and referencing them without explicitly calling their name (which is non-existent), or their relative index, since there are 10 items. What is this code actually doing inside of these loops, and conclusively in these loops?

Comment: The second loop is running ten times, one time for each of the items in the list. `for i, particle in enumerate(my_particles):` means that each of those ten times, it will assign a different item in the list to the variable `particle`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you asking how a python `for` loop works without an index?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is assigning each item in your list to the variable `particle2`.

The canonical example here assigns each value in turn to the variable `item`

```
items = ['a', 'b', 3]
for item in items:
    print item
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a name is just a handle to an object. You can refer to the same object in multiple ways, not just by using its name.

Comment: well, more specifically, if I have ten objects, and object 6 is colliding with object 3, the code shown is actually assigning object 6 to "particle", and object 3 to "particle2" at moment they collide, since their location in memory is being modified each time they pass through the loop. I'm just not sure how this is happening. I understand that it's checking collision for each particle that isn't itself, but I'm not sure how it's doing this... I also know that the code that makes this work is the (my_particles[i+3:]), but I just can't seem to conceptualize the relationship.

Comment: The outer for loop is creating a sequence of values `(index, particle)` from the list `my_particles` where `index` is just counting up 0...nparticles, and `particle` is the object you created and added to the list previously that's located at`index` in the list.  In the second for loop, you're actually not comparing the current particle with all other particles; the `[i+3:]` says you're comparing the current particle with each particle that's at least 3 indexes later in the list than the current particle.  I'm not sure what part is difficult to conceptualize?

Comment: My impression is you're confusing yourself by focusing on 'their location in memory' as you say more than once.  That concept isn't particularly useful in Python.  You're simply referring to different instances of the `particle` object in the list.  The magic of determining if a collision happens or not happens in the `collide()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop/statement *pulls* each item out (in turn), assigns it to the variable name you have supplied, then the *suite* is executed. The for statement only works with iterable objects. The for loop/statement doesn't know what is inside of the list and it really doesn't care. I'm paraphrasing the docs, perhaps a look at them will help - [The for statement](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).